# Authorization for API Gateway to service already storing user credentials

Tags: authorization, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a web service that users can sign into and so forth. I'd like to setup AWS API Gateway to allow the users to interact with the service via APIs. As the user management / password management is already in the system I don't want the user to have to go to another system.

I first looked at Cognito user pools but I couldn't automate fully the user creation / verification process, AWS in a support ticket said the user would have to verify the email separately. They then suggested to use a Lambda function to setup authorisation.

I've created a Lambda function and the API Gateway is authorizing however it looks like only one variable is sent for authorization, the `Identity token`. If I did this my Lambda function could find from my service that the key is valid but it's not really associated for a user.

What I'm after is a way to provide a user with a client id and passkey from my system (I can generate all of that), the user then does a request to the API Gateway end point with the client id and passkey, gateway sends the client id and passkey to the lambda function that calls my system for verification, Lambda returns the valid policy, API Gateway then sends the request to my service with either the client ID or some other identifier thats come back from the policy so my system knows the requesting client.

What would be the best way to achieve this without taking the user to a seperate system (Cognito)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that your timing might have just been a Day or so early. What you would have experienced with custom authorizers before is the `TOKEN` authorizer. Today they noticed expanded support for custom authorizers with a new `REQUEST` authorizer type. The new `REQUEST` type supports a much expanded dataset for authorizing requests, such as request parameters, headers, query strings, and more. Check out the [Custom authorizer types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#api-gateway-custom-authorizer-types) for further information.

Comment: Wait so they just released the feature I was after?

Comment: Apparently, like the day after your question (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-api-gateway-now-supports-enhanced-request-authorizers/)

Comment: Just tested it out, worked a treat and was exactly what I was after.